# php hide url parameters but still wants to get the values of those parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, urlrewriter

A simple question I've searched and tried all sorts of rewrite rules... no success... can anyone kindly show me how to hide the url parameters

for example 
i got the following url

```
http://localhost/legalHQ/public/agent/index.php?id=myid&id2=myId2
```

but i only want to show the following in the address bar but still want to get those parameters without showing it to user.

```
http://localhost/legalHQ/public/agent/index.php
```

I've seen so many similar questions but I cant get that working

i even tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

no success and please dont ask any thing about rewrite rules no idea about them..

thanks

Comment: make a `POST` type of request

Comment: There's no way if you don't want to use a POST request. This is the difference between GET and POST requests: GET have parameters in the URL. A very ugly way could be check, in your index.php if you have params. If you have, store them in SESSION and redirect to index.php without params. After redirecting, since there's no GET params, you can retrive the SESSION data and remove them (but this is ugly, unsecure and don't allow refreshing page)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry can't comment, not enough reputation, so adding this as an answer.

If sending the data as POST is not an option you can write an intermediate page say

```
    http://localhost/legalHQ/public/agent/process.php
```

that will store the GET parameters into the global session array and then just redirect to the

```
    http://localhost/legalHQ/public/agent/index.php
```

page where you can retrieve them from the session.